# need help about iOS crash log

Tags: iphone, ios, crash-dumps, crash-reports

What is cause of iOS crash?

```
Incident Identifier: FC439738-A111-4D56-B933-C6DC9EDCD803
CrashReporter Key:   cc6fa311f4d178cd2a1c946ced641fab87e0181d
Hardware Model:      iPhone2,1
Process:         iPORTALs [4452]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/26E8F5BC-CAFE-4280-B96E-3C6D319DDF48/iPORTALs.app/iPORTALs
Identifier:      iPORTALs
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  crunchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-05-22 11:28:40.514 +0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.3 (8J2)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xf039cde6
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32da1c98 objc_msgSend + 16
1   iPORTALs                        0x000801a0 0x1000 + 520608
2   iPORTALs                        0x00080930 0x1000 + 522544
3   iPORTALs                        0x0006eb0a 0x1000 + 449290
4   Foundation                      0x338a16ce __NSFireDelayedPerform + 362
5   CoreFoundation                  0x32937a40 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 8
6   CoreFoundation                  0x32939ec4 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 844
7   CoreFoundation                  0x3293a83e __CFRunLoopRun + 1082
8   CoreFoundation                  0x328caebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
9   CoreFoundation                  0x328cadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
10  GraphicsServices                0x33433418 GSEventRunModal + 108
11  GraphicsServices                0x334334c4 GSEventRun + 56
12  UIKit                           0x32417d62 -[UIApplication _run] + 398
13  UIKit                           0x32415800 UIApplicationMain + 664
14  iPORTALs                        0x0000285e 0x1000 + 6238
15  iPORTALs                        0x000027d4 0x1000 + 6100

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x332a8fbc kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x30205032 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 706
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3020603a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 86
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x302055ea _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 186
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32c9658a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32c96bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x332a5c00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x332a5758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x329382b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3293a562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x328caebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x328cadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x3114b27e RunWebThread(void*) + 382
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32c9530a _pthread_start + 242
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32c96bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x332a5c00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x332a5758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x329382b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3293a562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x328caebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x328cadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   Foundation                      0x338467f6 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 206
7   Foundation                      0x33839382 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                      0x338ab5c6 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32c9530a _pthread_start + 242
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x32c96bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x332a7d18 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32cbc860 _pthread_cond_wait + 756
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32c63eb2 pthread_cond_wait + 26
3   CoreMedia                       0x330808f4 WaitOnCondition + 4
4   CoreMedia                       0x3308083a FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 66
5   MediaToolbox                    0x31bb6a64 fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 48
6   CoreMedia                       0x3309e4dc figThreadMain + 156
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32c9530a _pthread_start + 242
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32c96bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x332a7c60 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3293d8f2 __CFSocketManager + 582
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32c9530a _pthread_start + 242
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32c96bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x332a83ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32c966d8 _pthread_wqthread + 592
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32c96bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x039eb9f0    r1: 0x32872008      r2: 0x00094841      r3: 0x00000004
    r4: 0xf039cdde    r5: 0x00094841      r6: 0x05454ac0      r7: 0x2fdfea30
    r8: 0x0022cbf0    r9: 0x0be90d54     r10: 0x00213360     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x0009b434    sp: 0x2fdfea20      lr: 0x000801a7      pc: 0x32f3ec98
  cpsr: 0x00070030

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x9afff +iPORTALs armv6  <aa5f4509b0ff3d15b3990afb0d6db84e> /var/mobile/Applications/26E8F5BC-CAFE-4280-B96E-3C6D319DDF48/iPORTALs.app/iPORTALs
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe25fff  dyld armv7  <bb9bfc7d242331d29a79adf7ef7aaa18> /usr/lib/dyld
0x301a4000 - 0x301b3fff  Notes armv7  <d9c976ca976e3d029f69febd48f17601> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x301bc000 - 0x301f3fff  Security armv7  <6599f42a910b3b31a0e1d98c883d61cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x30222000 - 0x30242fff  AppleAccount armv7  <4e0ac5cf93b338ab8c5f34ba3c5e2ee4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x30243000 - 0x3024cfff  CoreVideo armv7  <ea847e6dba2d36b1826b255c73b39539> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x3024d000 - 0x30253fff  IAP armv7  <c0f4c99a1b493e489948f231ad9238e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x3027d000 - 0x30286fff  ITSync armv7  <ba8b48d061903e4096774344448776d0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x30287000 - 0x30293fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <c68262667ac8397a949ce4e92dfec7db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x30294000 - 0x30299fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9d7198e91de9386a9e5ea43608a66a57> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x302e0000 - 0x302e1fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <39bf0f48bd8539169a77f8f61cdcd4c9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x3039c000 - 0x303a9fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9a0511ad5ebc3db898f1f49ed1a73d34> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x30470000 - 0x30489fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4825c3e392983aba947eca06555e4480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x304e0000 - 0x304ebfff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <ac706bee36593dc683fd5a96a389d72e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x305f7000 - 0x30645fff  CoreMotion armv7  <58c353bb7e33361f881da07c72f4cdfb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x30646000 - 0x3064cfff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <f9277ee9b85b3722975ad319a323aca0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x30675000 - 0x30675fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <f47c01d627853b328e088b3fdd08e87d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x30676000 - 0x306d5fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <0b36b2272aa33a8c9aa22d99c89d7189> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x306d6000 - 0x306d6fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <21415179ffa03f949fa8cc851c6c31c7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x307e4000 - 0x307e5fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <41a7b5e5d9983449ab33affed0f635ad> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x307e6000 - 0x3081bfff  AddressBook armv7  <3f2071a77bc134cd82065eef90d4082f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x3086e000 - 0x308a6fff  IOKit armv7  <80ae313ad69d3363935c88e51a11862d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x308aa000 - 0x308acfff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <d55f1553d14831a2a5435ae27ef75ef4> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x308b8000 - 0x308bbfff  CertUI armv7  <9060fe03a4943ef295531feced9a17dd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x308cd000 - 0x308cffff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <683f321680763e519d61541170ba2133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x30a14000 - 0x30b18fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <61a94142e2d23dafa2964190dd46e9e3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x30b19000 - 0x30b3dfff  MediaControl armv7  <1cfc7d79f554357ab59eb69f9efebf07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControl.framework/MediaControl
0x30b3e000 - 0x30b44fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <14c89b7346433c1f8675f454531f6ca3> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x30b45000 - 0x30b4afff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <c7cfe523e2d73521abc01587313ef730> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x30b4b000 - 0x30b4bfff  Accelerate armv7  <7d5ad465049136afaa1f0d89aac600bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x30b99000 - 0x30c42fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <5538d3f2c7d83b88b06168488fe6326b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x30f5f000 - 0x30f75fff  EAP8021X armv7  <9fefc0ada30435fbb3b51818c74f6cb8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x30f82000 - 0x30f85fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <fc834fd33a18341ea7506587ad895703> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x30f86000 - 0x3100afff  AVFoundation armv7  <eeaf5f4f822436a5bd1655f536e69879> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x3101b000 - 0x3101ffff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d2f7fd2a352b3cd59c564be34b53cf80> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x31020000 - 0x31027fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0a082e1d475432959ba93aa3dbf7fb31> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x31056000 - 0x31059fff  ArtworkCache armv7  <4863e321afee3ac5a3749e50cd926597> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache
0x3108e000 - 0x310d5fff  MessageUI armv7  <35a81f5d4eb03467a1447db80337e570> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x310d6000 - 0x310fffff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <57fef84bdc17301d8bf53ba0fb967fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x31103000 - 0x31132fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <1d73b8a159363f96bb9c039655c5eae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x31133000 - 0x31166fff  AppSupport armv7  <0217468bd9f839229a47910b7816b3d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x31167000 - 0x3117ffff  iAd armv7  <4a54026f52883c0fa28bf7e78fc12f44> /System/Library/Frameworks/iAd.framework/iAd
0x312e2000 - 0x318edfff  WebCore armv7  <07941e59d0a33f94802c16c76238fddf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x31945000 - 0x31a99fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <6619c8c13f8d328e923e797fa8d0df23> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x31a9c000 - 0x31bbdfff  CoreGraphics armv7  <65f6c8701b563542820a26b0dfc4f6a4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x31bbe000 - 0x31bc0fff  MailServices armv7  <74ae0145ef713c6d91fd8f68885b0a61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x31bc1000 - 0x31bc1fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <42d8aa2a31843a6e8bfff745644a7ba5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x31bc2000 - 0x31c4cfff  Message armv7  <2cce1aa95a493906bb0227197f9e4b96> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x31ca1000 - 0x31cadfff  HomeSharing armv7  <2df6957cdfea31aea12eebf27ca1691c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x31cae000 - 0x31cb5fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <55f29184efcc3046bb833dd72a4487e1> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x31d50000 - 0x31e9cfff  MediaToolbox armv7  <482b13059e8a329fa5d832baede25103> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x31eb3000 - 0x31eb5fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <9e7efa009730322f84bbc5d8bf1ded94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x31eb6000 - 0x31ec0fff  AccountSettings armv7  <d083fb384dc7311eb6766b9b2d2dd9c8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x31ec9000 - 0x31ed6fff  DataDetectorsUI armv7  <d454cde062983860a41694922eb5c042> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x32089000 - 0x32191fff  CoreData armv7  <9843a401dd1d322383e3e40021cc8b95> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x324d3000 - 0x324d5fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <a2631ac302f4310dae8367939e16b7c2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x324d6000 - 0x32573fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <e354aeb3d96e30338e90cc3638ffe81b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x32574000 - 0x32578fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a0772a32cd8b3b9194bb0c29807c1c5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x32586000 - 0x32913fff  UIKit armv7  <c271b78464d93cb7bf28c6e49df293ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x32916000 - 0x3295cfff  CoreTelephony armv7  <af7d1e770e5a3ffd8834a57fb5d40557> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x3295d000 - 0x32990fff  QuickLook armv7  <29d2d981d1d6358381f5716ee37314b4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x329ad000 - 0x329b4fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <ab9777b39e8e3026ad64dc90323cad7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x32a00000 - 0x32a34fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <570c63dc3a273a5a8c9072fd5567f5c1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x32a35000 - 0x32a5efff  ContentIndex armv7  <ecd71782cd833360872b943ecc65d203> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x32a5f000 - 0x32b44fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <a8444f997111304c9571b3ff974b769c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x32b45000 - 0x32b8ffff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <b2cac408951c3f3c9ba3cf563e54ce81> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x32b90000 - 0x32cbcfff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <113de5f9858c32b8b158bfdc68042a97> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x32ced000 - 0x32d2cfff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <33dcf9a403ae3fd5971d6030ada2fcab> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x32da0000 - 0x32de2fff  CoreAudio armv7  <c972fd5f8e89333ca680b9a33587f896> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x32dff000 - 0x32e80fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <a7077267b6743ed3bbdd86d4380c75d9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x32e81000 - 0x32ea1fff  MobileSync armv7  <4df400c4559435889eccd88db77a110c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x32ea2000 - 0x32ea7fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <f5ccc8234aea3ebd9a88bd37f0fa23ae> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x32ee2000 - 0x32ef2fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <66d9047da79a31daa887e6d84c42ecb2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x32f3c000 - 0x33000fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <6b51e76fde9f381bb7b3bc5badbfee3a> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x33011000 - 0x33080fff  ProofReader armv7  <6d843c6aecdd37ae84baa40af8ad7e65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x33081000 - 0x33094fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <529ea6e3a87230ce9f6cf3285c22429c> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x3309d000 - 0x330a0fff  ApplePushService armv7  <015c68c15621348db9f6a012499170e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x330e4000 - 0x331d1fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <f4146ce07e3031ea8a81fa5516fd77d0> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x3321b000 - 0x3325bfff  CoreMedia armv7  <8e0570582ba535bfa74f1f00eef64376> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x3325c000 - 0x332adfff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <8a41cc6a6d9332308bc415d27577fd24> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x332b1000 - 0x332b4fff  ActorKit armv7  <f7aa6cdd654231988aafcf448978f450> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x332d1000 - 0x33317fff  CoreLocation armv7  <c1924042951e3df98515c7bf36093c1c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x33433000 - 0x3344afff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <a06ec84e53bf32098b63c0caebdb45b6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x3344f000 - 0x334f5fff  Celestial armv7  <7fbd02fa664b33babaf0327c320d1491> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x334f6000 - 0x334f9fff  IOSurface armv7  <ad50e71624583d06b891344d832f9b08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x334fd000 - 0x33556fff  EventKit armv7  <0d4e597ee229337183e96e921a72e30a> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x33557000 - 0x33594fff  CoreText armv7  <fb6a72faec2330c4b2cd33c2e9c59588> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x335c3000 - 0x335cbfff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <63f11756c4aa3262b2317ff3b8e2a977> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x335cc000 - 0x335d8fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <ff78a9636e933f0dbd222f8d26209788> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x335dc000 - 0x3361ffff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <f790c26852cb3cf298abe56bc9a3940b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x33623000 - 0x33640fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <48016be86e3f3cd9aeee1c6590e1ac6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x3371a000 - 0x3371efff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e1cbfe599c96369ca4bdb0dd99d3cd9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x3371f000 - 0x33728fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <03d98d5cf6383695aa7d8a88da52f410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x3379d000 - 0x337abfff  OpenGLES armv7  <5a76beaeaa013f0cbf16e5cb154598ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x338c5000 - 0x338fdfff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <ccea634795153164a681f0f311f4461d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x33956000 - 0x33984fff  MIME armv7  <60de1fe0bbb134d788c09f7c34b1caa4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x339b9000 - 0x33ad8fff  Foundation armv7  <09ff368178c5321c9715b9c8d491d53f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x33ad9000 - 0x33adbfff  MobileInstallation armv7  <94b6d6c5d9883175af26764567528127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x33af4000 - 0x33b09fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e92cfbb83f7b330db19181e797bb3f7b> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x33b0a000 - 0x33b0ffff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <8c35c090bc373cb181fc26b961b8dba5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x33b10000 - 0x3555efff  TextInput armv7  <f242acc046073c1598195dd26fd8ad6f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x35563000 - 0x35583fff  PrintKit armv7  <e5a01ca9083a36afacc08611a398e2ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x3567a000 - 0x35729fff  QuartzCore armv7  <ef9632c9781f3101916b65e9faae1579> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x3572a000 - 0x35738fff  DataDetectorsCore armv7  <e54fa5bf6f9333618401cdbaf665f227> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x3573a000 - 0x3576dfff  iCalendar armv7  <34ce1957082f3518b5740ac33cfc92eb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x357c5000 - 0x357d5fff  WebBookmarks armv7  <6956561235333e74b8ff316cb2edc93e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x357d6000 - 0x35895fff  CFNetwork armv7  <b09e0d53de9f3bc8bde494780f3cdd4f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x3598d000 - 0x359bbfff  DataAccess armv7  <3a2e67aa1d8834b7a8fc2fbb56654b15> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x35a79000 - 0x35a88fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <563a09bcdb2f32369b1e22f53f58273a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x35a95000 - 0x35b56fff  RawCamera armv7  <0c52d8b1498c3dbb9aad95f3bcd8261d> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x35b57000 - 0x35b58fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <ccc041df3de73eafb7a59e74cdb1702b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x35b7c000 - 0x35b81fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <e57c2b9054b831d9a37119baaa4947cb> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x35d50000 - 0x35d57fff  WebUI armv7  <74070ad76277301fba6d3a5eb5f214b1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebUI.framework/WebUI
0x35d70000 - 0x35d71fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <e8858a499d663e6a9e3c188521273cc1> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x35d72000 - 0x35d7ffff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0a1e2bb78d5138419ecad8ba0fe42fdd> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x35dab000 - 0x35e71fff  MusicLibrary armv7  <71a09022bd8b3b6a90a250199d190f10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x35ec3000 - 0x35ed5fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <659ea9d5b13d3fefb37acff09016a69c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x35f12000 - 0x35f45fff  StoreServices armv7  <d526715648f435c3aac4c42953e76d20> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x35fc8000 - 0x35fc9fff  DataMigration armv7  <42e9e87a4e0735c3837e27d4f2adcf55> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x36062000 - 0x360b7fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <0221caba81a235c5a896a835e2aac047> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x360b8000 - 0x363a5fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <b855d60dac01310495453bddfd004f0d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x363af000 - 0x363ebfff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9d97699e44ee3651ba4ac37e5adec35b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x3649a000 - 0x3654bfff  WebKit armv7  <eb9a0d69c64b3127b2bffd71641add3b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x3654c000 - 0x3654ffff  MediaRemote armv7  <0804293b2774359189f3a67e2c81558d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x36550000 - 0x36550fff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <ffe9658cbc6e3464898da2d12f1a66d2> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x365b5000 - 0x365b6fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7b83cd757da73e6e826693c29296d3fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x365b7000 - 0x366c9fff  MediaPlayer armv7  <da848c0745a637af81d7edd962a09324> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x366cd000 - 0x366d0fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <43311c113a9d3182b7d007129819f029> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x366d1000 - 0x367ebfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <bada0c2725bb31a483d5adf9aaf1f8df> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x367ec000 - 0x367ecfff  vecLib armv7  <0c60cd0a60f43d2791d36cb357d30e3c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x36822000 - 0x368b7fff  ImageIO armv7  <d520e3241d1130e8ac1375ee0f2c1095> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x368e6000 - 0x36934fff  GMM armv7  <049361f664eb3f30b0d25cd56ffc1f0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x36935000 - 0x36954fff  Bom armv7  <b178e3efb4d733c694bd5a55e57a314f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
```

Comment: Are you using timers? Are you `invalidating` and `release`-ing the timer object before the `delegate` is released?

Comment: No, i use performSelector:@selector() is it possible to crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line: `Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)` tells you that you are trying to perform operations on an object that is already released. To be able to see what object you are trying to access enable `nszomibies`.

To enable zombies:

- in xcode 4+ go to "Edit schemes"
- select "Run appname.app" tab
- go to "Arguments"
- Add new entry to the "Environment variables"
- Entry name "NSZombieEnabled" and give it a value YES

Now run your code again and it should tell you what object you released prematurely.